# Disqus Comment Character Limit

Tags: disqus

Is there any way to limit the number of characters for a comment using Disqus?

I would like to restrict the comments character limit to 500 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to restrict the characters in a comment with Disqus at the moment. You can check out our [blog](http://blog.disqus.com/) to stay ahead of new features (should we introduce this), and leaving comments with well-thought suggestions have worked before.